# How to clear a value of a custom control in React js

Tags: reactjs

I have a custom control that is accessed from a parent control using:

> this.refs.myControl

the custom control consists of a div with input text inside the div, wrapped in a `span` tag

If I print out `this.refs.myControl` I can see all the properties of the control but cannot see the value entered by the user. 
What I want to do is clear the user-entered value when a button is clicked. I tried just clearing the state but that does not clear the value from textbox.

What is the best way to do that?

Here is my component:

```
class Control extends React.Component {


        render() {
            if(this.props.type==1) {
                //input text
                return(<div>
                    <span>{this.props.label}</span>
                    <span>
                        <input type="text" name={this.props.name} id={this.props.name} onChange={this.props.localChange} /> 
                    </span>
                </div>); 
            } else if (this.props.type==2) {
                return(<div>
                    <span>{this.props.label}</span>
                    <span>
                        <textarea name={this.props.name} id={this.props.name} cols={this.props.width} rows={this.props.height}></textarea>

                    </span>
                </div>);

            } else if (this.props.type==3) {
                return(<div>
                    <span>{this.props.label}</span>
                    <span>
                        <select name={this.props.name} id={this.props.name} onChange={this.props.localChange} >
                         <option value="">- Select -</option>
                            {
                                this.props.values.map(function(option, index) {
                                    return <option key={index} value={option.value}>{option.text}</option>;
                                })
                            }
                        </select>

                    </span>
                </div>);

            } else if (this.props.type==4) {
                return(<div>
                <input type="submit" name={this.props.name} id={this.props.name} value={this.props.label} onClick={this.props.localClick} style={buttonStyle} />
                </div>);

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your Components related code?

Comment: @mrlew, I added my component code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest in your input element bind your state variable in value field.

e.g.

```
class Test extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    this.state={
      myValue: ''
    };
  }

  render(){
    let {myValue} = this.state;
    return(
      <input
         onChange={(event)=>{
            this.setState({
               myValue: event.target.value
            });
         }}
         value={myValue}
         placeholder="My Control"/>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: my onChange event comes from parent. How do I get around that?

Comment: Then pass a function in props and call that function of the parent passing the required values.If you need a jsfiddle for that i can provide that.